# How do I keep the old version of custom Workflow?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, workflow

This might be a simple question because I'm pretty new in developing customer workflow.

I used Visual Studio 2010 to create a simple workflow (version 1). If I modify the workflow and deploy it again, the version 1 is gone. The active tasks in version 1 are deleted too. How can I keep the workflow version 1 and its tasks when I deploy a new version of workflow?

Answer (score 0):

This blog describes how to version your workflow, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yardman/archive/2010/04/14/versioning-a-visual-studio-sharepoint-workflow.aspx

and this http://blog.philwicklund.com/fff/2010/06/sharepoint-workflow-versioning-with-visual-studio-2010.html

see if it helps you.